# Orthogonality of vector functions created from orthogonal functions

Tags: vector-spaces, orthogonality

Say I have a vector X where X = (x1, x2, x3, ...), some finite number of scaler values. If I take two orthogonal scalar functions, say g(x) and f(x), and create two corresponding vectors such that G(X) = (g(x1), g(x2), g(x3), ...) and F(X) = (f(x1), f(x2), f(x3), ...), will G and F be orthogonal?

Please help me with the terminology here. It's been rough trying to search this when I'm not sure what terms to use.

Comment: What do you mean by "orthogonal scalar functions"? [I know what you mean by "scalar functions"; I just don't know what you mean by calling two of them orthogonal.]

Comment: @GerryMyerson two orthogonal functions like sin(x) and cos(x)

Comment: And what is it that makes those two functions orthogonal? In what sense are they orthogonal?

Comment: @GerryMyerson The integral of their product over an interval is zero

Comment: Actually if you change the domain interval of the functions, you get a different orthogonality relation. The answer is no. By the way search terms are 'Hilbert space', $L^2$

Comment: @Berci got it, thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it have been really easy to just pick some pair of functions and some numbers $x_1$ and $x_2$ and check to see what happens? Mathematics is not a spectator sport!